# Interacting Corda with Custom application

Tags: corda

I have an custom application with data and need to enhance the application to start the corda flows itself when i trigger it.

I found the same requirement but found no exact solution.

[https://discourse.corda.net/t/using-corda-for-a-school-project/1305/3](https://discourse.corda.net/t/using-corda-for-a-school-project/1305)

As per my understanding, I know that there are 2 ways to communicate with corda node.

1. Client RPC (which in turn talks to corda node)
2. Corda Node Web Server.

What are best approaches to make my external application talk with Client RPC to trigger flows when required as i want to automate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually only one way to speak to the Corda node - via RPC. Even the built-in node webserver uses RPC to speak to the node.

There are two main ways to interact with the Corda node via RPC:

- By writing an RPC client, like the one [here](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/com/example/client/ExampleClientRPC.kt). The client starts up, connects to the node, and issues it RPC commands
- By writing a server that speaks to the node via RPC. There are lots of options here. You can write a Spring webserver like the one [here](https://github.com/corda/spring-webserver), a Ktor webserver like the one [here](https://github.com/dev-slabs/ktor-rpc), or a server in any other JVM language. If you want to write your webserver in JavaScript instead, check out [this](https://github.com/joeldudleyr3/pigtail), which uses the Braid framework to communicate with the node in JS